# Python 3 PBKDF2HMACBackend default_backend() equivalent in java

Tags: java, python, cryptography

I have a task to rewrite some crypto code from python to java. I'm new in Python. Python sample:

```
import default_backend
backend = default_backend()    

PBKDF2HMAC(hashes.SHA256(), 32, salt, iterations, backend)
```

As I read [here](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/hazmat/primitives/key-derivation-functions/) 'backend' is an instance of PBKDF2HMACBackend.

I wrote the next code in Java:

```
SecretKeyFactory factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1");
SecretKey tmp = factory.generateSecret(new PBEKeySpec(???.toCharArray(), salt, iterations, 256));
```

In constructor of PBEKeySpec first parameter is password which is equivalent of 'backend' in python code. As I inderstand in python code it defined as default via library. But how I should define this parameter in my java code? Can I use some random value or constant? Or maybe some default_backend() equivalent exist?

UPDATED: full python code to get key:

```
PBKDF2HMAC(hashes.SHA256(), 32, salt, iterations, backend).derive("somePassword")
```

Comment: The whole backend business in the python cryptography package is a piece of inexplicable complexity offering zero benefit. I have no idea why it there at all. Java chooses the Java equivalent of this "backend" (called a *provider* in Java-ese) automatically when you call a `getInstance()` on one of the crypto classes. If in the rare case you absolutely must have a specific provider then you can use one of the `getInstance()` methods with a provider argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Python code, the password is passed in the `derive` method whose call is missing in the posted code, [here](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/hazmat/primitives/key-derivation-functions/#cryptography.hazmat.primitives.kdf.pbkdf2.PBKDF2HMAC):

```
kdf = PBKDF2HMAC(...)
key = kdf.derive(b'MyPassword')
```

The password doesn't correspond to the backend. The backend provides methods to support operations like encryption, hashing etc. and is described in more detail, [here](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/hazmat/backends/#backends).

Also note that in the Python code SHA256 is used and in the Java code SHA1. Since the Python code is the reference, `PBKDF2WithHmacSHA256` must be applied in the Java code.

Comment: "derive method whose call is missing in the posted code" - yes, it's my fault. So, I have to put the password inside new PBEKeySpec("mySuperPass".toCharArray()  ... ? Right?